# How to crawl latest articles in a specific domain using a specific set of websites?

Tags: web-crawler, nutch, crawler4j

I'm interested to build a program to get **all latest articles in a specific domain ("computer science") from a specific set of websites ("ScienceDirect" for example)**.
As you know, some websites publish a page for each research article, such as: http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S108480451400085X
Each page contains the information of a specific article.

I'm interested to know what is a best **tool (open source)** for this purpose?
General web crawlers (such as Apache Nutch) provide a general framework to crawl the whole web but in my case I need a **website(s)-specific crawler**.

Comment: try [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org)

Comment: You can easily do that by applying regular expression on regex-urlfilters.txt file in nutch. (of course if url format for your required pages is different from other pages)